# How do I fix non target cells from activating the sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Tags: excel, vba

My spread sheet has target cells and cells that I want to be able to enter manual data without the Worksheet Change to activate or run. How do I allow these open user cells to be populated without the private sub running??
More information sample code.  There are many code sections like this in the same format.

```
Private sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Intersect(Target, Range("$B$8:$k$9")) Is Nothing Then
        GoTo NEXT10
        'Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox Target.Address
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------    
    'Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = "$B$8" Then
        If Target.Value >= 0 Then
            Range("B9") = Range("B8").Value * 42
        End If
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$9" Then
        Range("B8") = Range("B9").Value / 42
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The problem is if I enter, delete value or text in any empty cells on the worksheet, it activates the `Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target ....)`.I use the `If Intersect(Target,Range($B8$:$k$8) Is Nothing` to bypass the target if no change. This format is used for other target ranges of important.  But I do not understand why when any cell is changed the program runs??  Can this be avoid so various manual entries can be performed?  For example text notes, labels, etc. 
The Next10 is the start of another section of code but with diferent target address.  If the target addess indicated is not intersected, it goes the check the next intersection.

Comment: Build the logic into the event macro.

Comment: What do you have in your Worksheet_Change that stops users changing any cells?

Comment: `Target` is the cell(s) you changed.  Make sure that Target [Intersects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) the correct range of cells.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` *always* runs when any change occurs (assuming events are not disabled) - you have to put the logic to decide whether and/or how to react in the sub itself

Comment: I will try to provide a little more information about the code and the cells.  Let me assemble the info.  Thanks

Comment: Where's `NEXT10` label?

Comment: The Next10 is the start of another section of code but with diferent target address.  If the target addess indicated is not intersected, it goes the check the next intersection.